# Checkout freezes on large orders

Tags: checkout, multistore, ee-1.12

We have a customer who is ordering over 1000 configurable products in qty's of 1-10. So probably 200+ configurable 'parent' products. It keeps freezing at checkout.

1) Is there anything I can do to improve this? 
I've disabled the gift note per item option. Disabled the RSS for the site.

2) would the 'order by sku' EE feature be less overhead? it seems to me like it would be as there is no parent/child connection to be made.

This is a multisite install (this large order is the wholesale 'website'), so changes need to be done at a website scope or less. IE, we don't want to change global options that effect the other stores, unless we don't really need them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)'s function [dev:module:observer:list](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#dev%3amodule%3aobserver%3alist) to check all observers that are in the community or local pool that have something to do with the checkout. Start by eliminating those extensions to see if it speeds up.

There are two small tricks that speeds up the checkout, maybe it helps. It concerns disabling the updates for RSS. You can safely do this if you're not using the RSS feeds for updating stock etc.  You can read how to do this [here on magbooster.com](http://www.magbooster.com/make-saving-order-in-magento-checkout-faster/).

Thirdly, enable the Profiler under System > Config > Advanced to see the bottlenecks in the process (and add '?profiler=1#profiler' to your URL to activate it on the front end). I advise you to install the [excellent Aoe_Profiler](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-profiler.html) extension to get a better overview of which calls take the most time. This is mainly for frontend processes though. A similar tool to view back end processes is [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/). Its an awesome tool but does cost a bunch of money though.

Comment: Disabling Mage Rss is basically snake oil in my opinion. I've never seen a reputable benchmark that proves that module (or any other) creates significant overhead. If you have a resource to point me toward with data along these lines I'd love to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Having benchmarked Magento I can safely say that checkouts **with 1000's of items** (configurable or otherwise) are **entirely possible** on a baseline Magento CE installation - **no EE required**. My immediate sense is that you may have an issue with customizations, installed 3rd party modules or integrations, or poor system specs (or an improperly configured setup).

Without having much more information than you've provided (entries in error logs, error code on failure, catalog size, memory allocation to PHP, etc.) there is no real means for me to help you debug your issue further than if you were to [follow the standard debug practice for Magento stores.](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/)

Off the top of my head here are a few things to check

- **Increase** your `memory_limit` from within your vhost/httpd.conf or htaccess file (or php.ini)
- **Check** the error logs for any obvious issues
- **Disable** all custom modules and repeat the checkout as a means of debugging
- **Attempt** to check out with the same cart structure from the backend admin panel - typically 3rd party modules neglect to hook into events on the admin side for checkout (in my experience).

Beyond that (basic triage) you should try to import your database against a plain old Magento 1.8/1.13 with the basic theme and attempt the checkout again. If it fails with a more concrete error, post it here, and we'll ammend our answers to help you further.

Cheers.

Comment: Fully agree, and often it comes down to inadequate hosting as checkout is one of the more resource intensive.